# How to get rid of maven snapshot versions

Tags: java, maven-2, build-process

I have been using maven for a while now. But I've never learnt how to get rid of the snapshot version.

Please share some articles on how to do a release of the artifacts.
i.e. how do I publish my 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT versions to (say) 1.0.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `mvn:release` plugin.

```
mvn release:prepare
mvn release:perform
```

That's about all you need to do, in the general case. See [**here**](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/introduction.html) for the more complete documentation.