# Maven executable jar with libraries on external path

Tags: maven, jar

My jar is not running, I can tell it tries to run as the log4j file manage to create the log folder but then nothing happens and the log is in blank.

My problem is I have the jar file in a folder called bin and the libraries in a folder called lib

I'm triying this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
    <outputDirectory>${staging.dir}/bin</outputDirectory>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
          <mainClass>com.Main</mainClass>
          <classpathPrefix>../lib/</classpathPrefix>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

and

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${staging.dir}/lib</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I also tried with maven-assembly-plugin, but it packs everything on the jar and I really need to have the folders bin and lib

What do I need to setup to make it work correctly?

EDIT: META-INF file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: me
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_26
Main-Class: com.Main
Class-Path: ../lib/ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar ../lib/sqljdbc4-4.2.0.jar ../lib/
mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar ../lib/hibernate-core-3.6.5.Final.jar
../lib/antlr-2.7.6.jar ../lib/commons-collections-3.1.jar ../lib/dom
4j-1.6.1.jar ../lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar ../
lib/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar ../lib/jta-1.1.jar ../lib/s
lf4j-api-1.6.1.jar ../lib/hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.5.Final.jar ../
lib/cglib-2.2.jar ../lib/asm-3.1.jar ../lib/javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar .
./lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar ../lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar ../lib/commons-
codec-1.5.jar ../lib/lablib-checkboxtree-3.3-20110114.141734-3.jar
```

SOLUTION

turns out the META-INF file is incorrect. The reason is that maven-archiver-plugin renames SNAPSHOT libraries with a timestamp as default behaviour

to override that use this, as instructed by the Maven Archiver doc:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
     <configuration>
       <archive>
         <manifest>
           <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
          <useUniqueVersions>false</useUniqueVersions>
          <mainClass>com.Main</mainClass>
          <classpathPrefix>../lib/</classpathPrefix>
         </manifest>
       </archive>
     </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

other than that, I hope people find useful the maven code at the start because it does work, just beware the SNAPSHOTS in your projects

Comment: How does your MANIFEST file look?  Also have you actually placed the dependant jars in lib folder?

Comment: everything is there and the MANIFEST looks good, just attaching to edit right now

Comment: youa re right is a META-INF issue, my last lib is lablib-checkboxtree-3.3-SNAPSHOT.jar, tried running the jar on console and it can't find the library. I tried removing and redownloading the lib but it keeps placing thtat numebr instead of the word SNAPSHOT, why?

Comment: Yes, "useUniqueVersions" was the fix to the 'time stamping' problem as you named it, I had similar issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above all seems OK. Here are some things/questions you may want to try/confirm/answer:

- Are you running this from command line? I.e. using `java -jar <your.jar>` or are you starting it e.g. by double-clicking the file, etc.? If not, try running it from the command line to see what happens
- Try using `mvn exec:java` to see if that starts your app (maven-)regularly. See http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html if you are not familiar with exec plugin
- Can you use regular Java `System.out.println` instead of logging to confirm that it actually starts? Having a zero-size log might be a logging configuration issue
- I see you have some DB libraries above. Can you put some println (or better logging, but only after you confirm your logging actually works) statements around basic initialization, to confirm that you are not just stalling there (provided that's what's happening - you don't mention any exceptions or other issues in specific)

A lot depends on the actual application code, but hope some of the above might help you pinpoint the issue.

As a side note, is your main class really `com.Main`? If yes, may I suggest to change that to something more appropriate - e.g. `com.yourdomain.yourapp.Main` or something along these lines. Not that this will change the above result, just a stylistic comment.

Comment: I was double-clicking it, hence I wasn't seeing any errors, now that I used console I see it can't load the last library, the name should be lablib-checkboxtree-3.3-SNAPSHOT, however maven is changing it to that lablib-checkboxtree-3.3-20110114.141734-3, I changed the lib name manually and confirms it works, how to correct this?

Comment: and don't worry the name is not com.Main ;)

Comment: Can you try deleting the artifact from your `.m2` folder (see this if you are not familiar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081617/missing-maven-m2-folder) and then try `mvn package` again? You should find it in .m2/repository/<groupId>/lablib-checkboxtree/3.3-SNAPSHOT - just move that folder somewhere else (as a backup solution) and then reinstall it however you did before (did you use `mvn install:install-file` or do you have something like Nexus on site?). You should confirm you have lablib-checkboxtree-3.3-SNAPSHOT.jar there

Comment: > and don't worry the name is not com.Main ;)
Cool :)

Comment: Or better yet deploy it as a non-snapshot version - much better if you can do it (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758921/how-to-get-rid-of-maven-snapshot-versions)

Comment: wish I could, but thats the only available version of that component, hate when there is a good SWING component that goes discontinued

Comment: maven-archiver was overwritting the SNAPSHOT with a timestamp, found the documentation to override that :D

Comment: Well, SNAPSHOT is not a "version", it's actually a collection of versions - that's why you have the date, as that's the latest version in the SNAPSHOT set. These are used while developing, so you update code frequently, but should not be used in the final product. You can always use `mvn install:install-file` (check http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html) to upload it a whichever version you want (e.g. `3.3-javaNoober`, to if you want to signify it's for your use only), though do this carefully and only if you have to, with specific reasons.

Comment: As a (bad) alternative, you can use `stripVersion` option to dependency plugin, see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html.